In which show was someone named "Moo Goo Gai Pan"?
I just remembered about a TV show (or movie, maybe; I don't really recall most of it, but I think it was from TV), a cartoon, I think, in which there's an episode where someone has a trauma because his parents named him "Moo Goo Gai Pan", like the Chinese food, and in the end it somehow turns against him, with others making fun of him. Can someone help me remember where this plot is from?

Possibly Double Take, episode 3 of the animated show The Sylvester & Tweety Mysteries, where Granny's old flame frames her for a crime after she mocked his unfortunate name Moo Goo Guy Pan (which always plagued him). The episode is available on Youtube and the relevant bit starts at 12:05:



The character returns in the season 2 episode The Granny Vanishes.
